# (Rails) Unusual nested attributes quirk: params hash expects integer key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, nested-forms, nested-attributes, strong-parameters

I've ran into a problem when writing a nested form.

I got the error below :

```
TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer):
app/controllers/people_controller.rb:9:in `create'
```

Whitelisting of parameters:

```
        def person_params
          params.require(:person).permit(
            :id, :name, :role, :dob, 
            :work_place, :assessment_id, 
            :telephone, :occupation, 
            person_notes_attributes: [
                            :id, :is_referee, :is_requester,
                            :is_key_holder, :is_house_member, :is_present,
                            :is_visitor, :presence_explanation, :visitor_info
                            ] )
        end
```

Typical form element:

```
 <%= check_box_tag "person[person_notes_attributes][is_referee]", "true", false  %>
 <%= label_tag "person[person_notes_attributes][is_referee]", 'Requested referral?' %>
```

After some searching around I think I've homed into the nature of the problem which is described in the [blog post](http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2013/09/29/rails-tricky-error-no-implicit-conversion-from-symbol-to-integer/).

The author indicates that this error is caused by how rails interprets the indexing of the params hash.

He notes:

> Rails expected params[:user][:keys_attributes] to use integers as keys (like an array does) but instead it found symbols.

In my case this would be

```
params[:person][:person_notes_attributes].
```

The difference between the authors case and mine is that they are doing `POST` of `json` data and providing default parameters.

Their solution is to fix the declared default parameters they provided by wrapping the `hash` in an `array element`.

I have tried their solution and while it lets me successfully save record for `PersonNote`, the `form inputs` do no override the defaults provided.

How can I solve this?

Ideally I'd like to reach a solution that doesn't require declaring defaults at all.

Comment: I have used nested attributes in a similar manner, but I needed to do `<%= check_box_tag "person[person_notes_attributes][][is_referee]", "true", false  %>` - note the extra square brackets. You then access the params by `params[:person][:person_notes_attributes][0]` i.e an array is passed of all attributes